# Set different prefixes for two role classes that inherit from GrantedAuthority

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have created two entites

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

     /*...*/

    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "roles_privileges",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id")
    )
    private Set<Privilege> privileges;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Privilege implements GrantedAuthority {

    /*...*/

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

What should i add in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity http)` method (or class itself) so that the Roles are distinguished with ROLE_ default prefix, and Privileges with PR_ prefix?

Comment: You can set default prefix to "" so you can check with other prefixes

Comment: How would i add the prefixes to those classes in that case? Should i do it manually in my repository/DAO?

Comment: Sure you can set Role_ prefix by inserting with row like Role_Admin also Pr_admin is valid role.

Comment: Define some auths with Role others with Pr. You can check token or granted authorities with @preauthorize tag

Answer (score 0):

You can add annotation @DiscriminatorColumn and specify details of what DType you want to use. This is done on both  entity

Comment: I thought of this solution, but i was wondering if this can be done in a convenient way without storing more data. Thanks anyway